# For which of the following functions is $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$?

Tags: functions, functional-equations

> For which of the following functions $f(x)$ is $f(a+b) = f(a) + f(b)$?
>
> (A) $f(x) = x^2$
>   (B) $f(x) = 5x$
>   (C) $f(x) = 2x+1$
>   (D) $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$
>   (E) $f(x) = x-2$

**Given solution:**

Let $a = 2$, and $b = 3$.

Then solve each of the given functions like the following:

[image]

the snap shot suggests that I should calculate all functions which I don't like.

**Is there any better method out there?**

Comment: Continuous linear functions are of the form $ax$. You should see the answer at a glance, without any computation. Remember there's a time constraint for the GRE

Answer (score 2):

( not better )

$$
f\left(a+b\right)=f\left(a\right)+f\left(b\right)
$$
For $a=b$ we have
$$
f\left(2a\right)=2f\left(a\right)
$$
Taking $a=0$ gives you $f(0)=0$ and for $b=-a$ we have $f(0)=0=f(x)+f(-x)$ so $f$ is odd.
Then you can show by induction that
$$
f(n)=nf(1)
$$
Then $f$ is odd so it is true for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$. With $r=p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$ we have
$$
f\left(r\right)=f\left(\frac{p}{q}\right)=pf\left(\frac{1}{q}\right) \text{ and }f\left(1\right)=f\left(\frac{q}{q}\right)=qf\left(\frac{1}{q}\right)
$$
So
$$
f\left(r\right)=\frac{p}{q}f\left(1\right)=rf\left(1\right)
$$
Then $Q$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$ so $f$ satisfies
$$
f\left(x\right)=xf\left(1\right)
$$
So the only solution is $f(x)=5x$ in your exercise.

Comment: You need to state continuity for the density argument to work.

Comment: Yes it is true !

Answer (score 2):

In such type of problems go by option verification.

A)$f(a+b)=(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab\neq f(a)+f(b)$

B)$f(a+b)=5(a+b)=5a+5b=f(a)+f(b)$

and so on$.....$ for other options

So, the option is $B$

**OR**
You can save time by using an intuitive method. Look for the expression that satisfies the distributive property $i.e.$ $x (y + z) = xy + x z$

When you put $(a+b)$, it should give individual functions in $a$ and $b$ which means that you will get two separate, comparable terms in $a$ and $b$. 
Squares, roots, addition and division by the variable does not satisfy the distributive property.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on Gabriel Romon's comment, a function $f$ that satisfies
$$
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)
$$
is called *linear*. This definition immediately restricts any function different from $f(x) = ax + b$, as you know from basic calculus that if $x$ has any power other then $1$ or $0$, then it's not linear (in the normal sense). This eliminates $(a)$ and $(d)$ immediately.

It remains to see if $f(x) = ax + b$ is *actually* linear, in this new sense. Quickly check that
$$
f(x + y) = a(x + y) + b = ax + b + y = f(x) + y \neq f(x) + f(y),
$$
so the constant $b$ stops $f$ from being linear. This means that all you're left with is $f(x) = ax$, so only option $(b)$ satisfies this.

This is a very 'hand wavey' argument, but I think it suffices for your purposes.

Comment: You could add that the function in the form $f(x)=ax+b$ is called affine.

Answer (score 1):

All constants will be counted only once in $f(a+b)$ but twice in $f(a)+f(b)$, so any functions with a constant are automatically excluded. In  this case, thats is $C$ and $E$.

When raising to powers, note that $(a+b)^n\ne a^n+b^n$ unless $n=1$, $a=0$, or $b=0$, thus any other  powers won't work. Thus $A$ and $D$ are ruled out. When $n=1$, then $k(a+b)^n=k(a^n+b^n)$, and so a function of the form $y=kx$ is perfectly valid, hence $B$ is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't solve any of them.

- I searched around a bit and reminded myself that the key here is the
  "**Distributive Property (of Multiplication) over Addition**".

  https://www.khanacademy.org/math/pre-algebra/pre-algebra-arith-prop/pre-algebra-ditributive-property/v/the-distributive-property

  This is why B will work.
- There is a distributive property over exponentiation, but it
  distributes over multiplication, not over addition.

  http://www.solving-math-problems.com/exponent-rules-distributive.html

  This is why A and D will not work.
- There is no distributive property (of addition) over addition.

  This is why C and E will not work.

You asked if there was another way.  Knowing why things work instead of just how to do the problems is a very good way.